# Get the node title field value in the form_state

Tags: nodes, forms, hooks, 9

Drupal version 9.3.9.

This is a process of Ajax callback, where the value of the title field is required. In the form node add, the title is displayed. It seems that the form_state does not apply to the title field. When I inspect the variables, the title field is also not reflected in the values.

```
function my_custom_module_field_widget_process($element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state,$form) {
  #$element['my_field']['#default_value'] =$form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()- 
  #>label();this work, but useless in the callback

  if(!empty($form_state->getValue('title'))){
    $title = $form_state->getValue('title');
    $element['my_field']['#default_value'] = $title;
  }
    
  return $element;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `$form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()->label();` works but is useless in the callback?

Comment: I mean, the value is stored after the node is been saving. I need the value in an Ajax callback. The user must see the value when entering the form so that they can change or edit the value.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if($node) {
        $title = $node->label();
    }
```